# Proper container for "start from scratch" CSS formatting?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to create a page that will be made up of various blocks containing questions and answers, like a survey with multiple choice answers.

Right now I'm using DIVs and then overriding the layout and format with CSS to keep each question in its own block and align the questions and answers, but this method doesn't seem to play well with every browser (IE mostly is the problem)

Is there a better container tag that I can use to contain each question that doesn't have existing formatting to override?

The questions are going to be processed in Javascript and are not contained in a form element because they won't be submitted to a server, so I'm just looking at the best way to achieve a simple block layout for each question.

Comment: *this method doesn't seem to play well with every browser* .... which method ?? DIV's are empty tags with the minimum format must be the CSS you are using

Comment: You'll have to learn a little bit more about HTML and CSS. This is a very broad question; and we'd have to essentially write you a chapter in a book to answer it properly.

Comment: To clarify what I meant... I was looking for some kind of container that I can use as a sort of root for CSS of the elements within.  In some questions, the answers are floated to the right of the question, while others are lined in a grid below the question.  As far as what wasn't "playing well" was that without the right container, the text wasn't wrapping properly around the floated answers in IE, instead pushing the answers down to the next line. The questions are also contained in a span tag as an inline-block, which may be why IE won't wrap around the floated element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simply answer your question, `<div>` is fine. Your divs should not have any preformatted layout styles associated with them, they are just general containers. If your css has styles for all divs in general, consider refactoring those styles into classes.

There are other tags like `<section>` but like I said there is no difference in terms of layout and formatting, that's all in the css.

If you have a more specific layout problem, feel free to post your html and css here for us to see.